# Yii2: data-method='post' is sending GET request

Tags: html, yii2, href

I am making changes in existing web page in yii2.
I had this section of code:

```
Html::a('Confirm!',[
        'default/apply',
        'confirm' => 1,
        'id' => $data->id
    ],['class' => 'btn-primary','data-method' => 'post'])
```

I have moved this to a different container on the same page.

(I had to adjust slightly, changing `$data->id` into `$projectInfo->id` as earlier it was inside anonymous function within a widget and now inside a `foreach` loop. But this should not be relevant I suppose.)

Both before and after the change the same line is present in html (but in different part of the page):

```
<a class="btn-primary" href="/participant/default/apply/13/1" data-method="post">Confirm!</a>
```

But on execution http request is now sent as GET instead of POST.

BEFORE: `"POST /participant/default/apply/13/1 HTTP/1.1"`

NOW: `"GET /participant/default/apply/13/1 HTTP/1.1"`

I cannot figure out why this changed and how to get the code to work as POST in new location. This href execution must depend on some additional factor that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send POST request using link thanks to JavaScript inside `yii.js` file that wraps it in form silently. If this JS is not loaded in assets link works in standard way which is sending GET requests.

Check if `yii.js` is loaded (usually through registering `yii\web\YiiAsset` directly or by dependency).

Comment: Thanks! That gave me a hint although it did not solve my issue entirely.

1. I have a reference to yii.js just before the end of `body` in html:
`<script src="/assets/24623ab5/yii.js"></script>`
This reference is valid. Can I check anything else to make sure it is loaded?

2. There is more complexity in JS in my page that might be affecting how this `href` is handled. I am still unsure why `data-method` related code is not executed but I have got a valid answer for my question.